# Unity3d Input.location from documentation not available in code

Tags: android, gps, location, unity-game-engine

I am working on a Unity3d for Android project.  Using the documentation from Unity:

http://unity3d.com/support/documentation/ScriptReference/Input-location.html

I should be able to use `Input.location` to get access to GPS location data.  But instead I get an error basically telling me the Input.location is not part of Unity.

> Assets/Scripts/Prototype1.js(27,29): BCE0019: 'location' is not a
>   member of 'UnityEngine.Input'.

I've checked for updates and it tells me the system is fully up to date.  I'm running version 3.4.2f3

Is the documentation outdated? Is there a different reference to the LocationService?  How can I get the location data?

Comment: As a note for anyone who finds this question. Always open the Unity3d scripting reference from inside Unity3d.  It's under  Help > Scripting Reference  As of right now, Unity's website shows the documentation for 3.5, but 3.5 is not the current stable release.  The iPhoneSettings for example are not listed on the Unity hosted reference, but are listed in your local installed reference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found documentation to the old code, based in iPhoneSettings.  This is the code I'm using now, it's not complete (doesn't respond to time out of the location service and other such well rounded behavior), but demonstrates the code.

```
function Start () {
    locationStatus = LocationServiceStatus.Stopped;

    StartCoroutine(startLocationService()); 
}

function Update () {
    if(locationStatus == LocationServiceStatus.Running)
    {
        /*
        lat = Input.location.latitude;
        lon = Input.location.longitude;
        alt = Input.location.altitude;
        */

        lat = iPhoneInput.lastLocation.latitude;
        lon = iPhoneInput.lastLocation.longitude;
        alt = iPhoneInput.lastLocation.altitude;
    }
}

function startLocationService()
{
    //Input.location.Start(accuracy, distance);
    iPhoneSettings.StartLocationServiceUpdates(accuracy, distance);

    //while(Input.location.status == LocationServiceStatus.Initializing && maxWait > 0) {
    while(iPhoneSettings.locationServiceStatus == LocationServiceStatus.Initializing && maxWait > 0)
    {
        yield WaitForSeconds(1);
        maxWait--;
    }

    //locationStatus = Input.location.status;
    locationStatus = iPhoneSettings.locationServiceStatus;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The files at unity3d.com contain the documentation for the most recent release Unity3D 3.5. If you look at your documentation in the local file system you won't find `Input.location`. Seems like they have changed the interface in Unity3D 3.5.

I haven't used GPS until now, maybe this thread and the links provided can throw some light on this:

[How to import GPS location coordinates from Android device?](http://forum.unity3d.com/threads/69696-How-to-import-GPS-location-coordinates-from-Android-device)

Comment: The last comment on that page was the hint that got me where I needed thanks.